# Android app that called external .exe

Tags: java, android, c++, c, java-native-interface

I am about to make an app on android but I have 0 experience about it.
This project is important and kind of a big challenge to me.
With that being said, I will try my best to explain about it so you guyz can give me an accurate approach

So assuming I have a program written in C,C++. Either an .exe or bunch of library.
What this executable do is to process the data and generate a file with bunch of binary and weird output. This process is called pre-processing.

Then result file will then be fed into Matlab or python and the graphical result will be generated. This is called post-processing and also the final goal.

Right now I can't afford to get matlab installed so my boss only asked me to go up to the pre-processing part.

The project will be displaying the pre-processing on the screen of a android device even if it might be unreadable.

I have done some research and found several ways to accomplish this:
1/ write a simple app using java and use JNI to call the main function of the .exe
2/ write a simple app using c++ and get the result straight from the .exe

That's all i can come up with, can any expert give me some suggestions please.
I am looking for a solution that would get me pass the pre-processing phase but also be efficient and easy if I get a chance to work on post-processing phase later.

Thank you very much

Comment: Please note that .exe refers only to Windows executables. Also - what is your question? You only gave us extremely vague requirements and ask for suggestions for a solution. Please update your question with things like: what sort of data processing are you doing, how big is your existing "C,C++" code base, what external libraries does it use. Also - you say you've done some research. What benefits, drawbacks and/or concerns do you see with the two solutions? How could they impact your requirements? These are all things we need to know to help you - http://whathaveyoutried.com/

Comment: the thing is that the C,C++ exe is extremely big and very complicated and I have absolutely no idea what and how the data is being processed. They only ask me how to make it run on android device, but the actual implementation of the .exe is beyond scope of my knowledge. But they run it on supper-computer so I suggest it is a very big application. But what is given to me is the pre-compiled version that already has data (hard-coded, if you will). I don't know if JNI would be a good approach, or also beside the two if there is alternative way that is more efficient.

Comment: So you're trying to run a super computer application on a smartphone... Are you sure you're not just supposed to take the output of the pre-processing stage and display it?

Comment: Exe can also refer to .net/mono executables

Comment: actually there was a guyz that make it run on an android emulator, so I don't think it would be impossible to run on real device.